# Not sure how to use css selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My html looks something like this:

```
<div id="whatever">
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would need to select all `p` elements, except the ones in the last `div` in the "whatever" one. I tried `#whatever>:not(:last-child)div>p`, but didn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so close! :) you just need `#whatever div:not(:last-child) p`  Depending upon the structure of your actual HTML, you might need to add the `>` back in, but for what you have above, this will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the order wrong. It should be this:

```
#whatever > div:not(:last-child) > p
```

(spaces added for readability)

If you specify a tag, the tag always comes first in that level of the selector.